# Windows not executing one exe

Tags: windows-installer, windows-server

I have a Windows 2016 Server and was in the process of updating Stunnel. I downloaded the latest version (**stunnel-5.56-win64-installer.exe**) and it downloaded without any apparent problems.

I double-click it and nothing happens.

I executed the *same*  installer on another Windows machine and it executed as expected.

Where can I look to see what is blocking this upgrade please?

Thanks

Comment: Does the process show up in task manager when you try to start it?

Comment: Have you tried to first uninstall the old version?

Comment: Does not show up in task manager. 
I (now) uninstalled the existing version and tried again and it failed again.

Comment: I then restarted and it ran through.
It would have been interesting to see a log of why it was failing

Comment: Was there nothing in the event viewer?

Comment: @Burgi: No it was clear.

Answer (score 1):

The solution came after uninstalling the existing version and rebooting the server.

While this behaviour was not necessary in earlier upgrades of the product it resolved the matter